# Is $E[E[X|Y,Z]|Y]=E[X|Y]$ for independence between X and Z only?

Tags: probability

Does $E[X|Y,Z]=E[X|Y]$ hold only for independence between X and Z or in general?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if $X=Z$ and $Y$ is independent of $X$?

Comment: then E[X|Y,X]=XE[1|Y,X]=X?

Comment: Yes, and $E[X|Y]=E[X]$.

Comment: I don't get the double conditioning on Y on the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The independence of $X$ and $Z$ does not guarantee that $E[X\mid Y,Z]=E[X\mid Y]$.

For an example, consider $Z=XY$ with $(X,Y)$ uniform on $\{-1,+1\}^2$ (equivalently, $X$ and $Y$ are independent symmetric Bernoulli random variables). Then $E[X\mid Y,Z]=X$ because $X=YZ$, while $E[X\mid Y]=E[X]=0$ because $X$ and $Y$ are independent and $X$ is symmetric.

Conversely:

> The fact that $E[X\mid Y,Z]=E[X\mid Y]$ does not guarantee the independence of $X$ and $Z$.

For an example, assume that $Z$ is $Y$-measurable, then $E[X\mid Y,Z]=E[X\mid Y]$ without any assumption on the dependence structure of $(X,Z)$.

**Edit:**

> The independence of $(X,Y)$ and $Z$ guarantees that $E[X\mid Y,Z]=E[X\mid Y]$.

To see this, note that $T=E[X\mid Y]$ is measurable with respect to $(Y,Z)$ hence, to check that $T=E[X\mid Y,Z]$, one just has to check that $E[T;(Y,Z)\in B]=E[X;(Y,Z)\in B]$ for every Borel set $B$, and that in fact, it suffices to check that $E[T;Y\in B,Z\in C]=E[X;Y\in B,Z\in C]$ for every Borel sets $B$ and $C$.

To show this last statement, first note that $T$ is $Y$-measurable and that $Y$ and $Z$ are independent hence $E[T;Y\in B,Z\in C]=E[T;Y\in B]\cdot P[Z\in C]$. Furthermore, $T=E[X\mid Y]$ hence $E[T;Y\in B]=E[X;Y\in B]$. On the other hand, $(X,Y)$ and $Z$ are independent hence $E[X;Y\in B,Z\in C]=E[X;Y\in B]\cdot P[Z\in C]$. This proves the claim.

Comment: Thanks! I believe I understand the proof. However, I got confused by my statistics textbook. It writes there: "Because $(\epsilon_i,x_i)$ is independent of $(\epsilon_j, x_1,.., x_{i-1},x_{i+1},...,x_N)$, we have: $E(\epsilon_i|x_1,x_2,...,x_N, \epsilon_j)=E(\epsilon_i|x_i)$. Does it mean that the argument in the book works because of the joint distribution $(\epsilon_i,x_i)$ being independent of all other conditions?

Comment: It does. See Edit.

Comment: great job! I am all happy :)